# Git: how to modify the content (not commit message) for the HEAD^^ commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

Suppose I worked on:

- feature 1:  file1 + file3
- feature 2:  file2

and I have the following commits

- Commit 2:   feature 2 completed.
- Commit 1:   Feature 1 completed.

The wrong thing I made is I forget to add the file3 to commit 1.  How can add the changes of file3 to commit 1?

One way of this is:

```
git reset --soft Commit 1
git add file3
git commit --amend 
git add file2
git commit -m "feature 2 completed"
```

I don't want this way is because in fact I may not only have commit 2 but also have commit 3,4,5,6...

is there other easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--i) is the command you need. But it will produce the results you expect only if the history line you want to change is linear (i.e. no merges).

Comment: Thanks @axias,  I did found git rebase -i before but don't know how to choose the p/r/e/s/f/x/d stuff in this case.  do you mind to provide an example of this?

Comment: @axiac how can you change commit contents when interactively rebasing?

Comment: It is explained in the documentation of [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits). You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27399649/4265352) that explains how to follow the recipe provided in the documentation using a GUI Git client. It explains how to split a commit but the concept is the same: you can use `git rebase -i` to ***modify*** a commit created in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you cannot modify *any* commit.  Even `git commit --amend` does not do that.  Remember that each commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID.

What you *can* do is take some existing commit, extract it, and use it to build a new, *different* commit that is *almost* the same as the original commit, but with whatever it is that you consider flawed, fixed.  You must then convince everyone—yourself, and anyone who has cloned the commit—to stop using the old, flawed commit, using the shiny new one instead.  The new commit has a new, *different* hash ID.

If the shiny new commit is *not* at the tip of a branch—if it's two steps back, as in this case, for instance—then you have an additional problem.  Remember, branch names like `master` and `develop` identify *one particular commit*, which Git calls the *tip* commit of the branch.  Each commit also contains the hash ID of its *parent* (previous) commit, and this is how Git finds the earlier commits from the latest:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Here, the uppercase letters stand in for the big ugly hash IDs.  The name `master` identifies commit `G`: the *tip* of `master`.  The name `develop` identifies commit `K`, the tip of `develop`.  From commit `G`, Git can work backwards to `F`, then `E`, and so on.  From `K`, Git can work backwards to `J`, and eventually to `E` and so on.

If there is a problem in commit `I`, what you can do is have Git extract commit `I`, make some change to the index-and-work-tree pair (just like you would do for any other commit), and then make a *new* commit—let's call it `I'` to indicate that it's the replacement for `I`—whose parent is the same as `I`'s parent:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- develop
           \
            I'  <-- temporary
```

Having done that, we now just need to have Git copy `J` to a shiny new `J'` whose parent is `I'` and whose effect on `I'` is the same as `J`'s effect on `I`:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- develop
           \
            I'-J'  <-- temporary
```

Now we repeat the trick for `K` to make `K'`:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- develop
           \
            I'-J'-K'   <-- temporary
```

Finally, we tell Git: *Drop the temporary name.  Make the name `develop` identify shiny new commit `K'` instead of icky old `K`.*  This gives us:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J--K   [abandoned]
           \
            I'-J'-K'   <-- develop
```

and if we stop *drawing* the abandoned branch it looks as though we have somehow *changed* three commits.  But we have not: the new commits have new, different hash IDs.

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I'-J'-K'  <-- develop
```

This is what `git rebase -i` does.  It sounds like a lot of work, and in some cases it can be, but usually `git rebase -i` makes it easy and painless for *you*.

Note that if you have pushed `develop` elsewhere, you must now *force*-push this new develop, to tell the other Git that received commits `I`, `J`, and `K` that it should *forget* those commits (and any later ones as well!) and instead use the shiny new replacements.

If other users have picked up the original `I-J-K` sequence, you must convince *them* to discard *their* `I-J-K` copies too.  If they have built their own commits atop `K`, you have to get them to copy their old commits atop your shiny new `K'`.  This can be noticeable amounts of work for all the other users, so be sure you really want to do this to them.